# Google Address API for dynamic input type

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use google address API for autofill address. I am able to implement it with below input type.

```
<input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"
         onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
```

But in my code, there can be multiple address and that is not static. i.e, input type can be added or removed from the javascript.

Here is a snapshot of form.
[image]

After clicking on add address the page looks like this.

[image]

I dont know how to apply google address API on this dynamic generated input field.

Below is the javascript for google address API.

```
<script>
      // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
      // of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

      var placeSearch, autocomplete;
      var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name'
      };

      function initAutocomplete() {
        // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
        // location types.
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
            {types: ['geocode']});

        // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
        // fields in the form.
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
      }

      function fillInAddress() {
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        for (var component in componentForm) {
          document.getElementById(component).value = '';
          document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
        }

        // Get each component of the address from the place details
        // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
          var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
          if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
          }
        }
      }

      // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
      // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
      function geolocate() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var geolocation = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
              center: geolocation,
              radius: position.coords.accuracy
            });
            autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
          });
        }
      }
    </script>
```

In this questions address type fields can be more than 2.

Comment: Question is not duplicate as in that question the fields are of fixed number and their id are fixed wherein in this case fields are dynamic and it can be more than 1.